# py manage.py dumpdata withoutrest.employee --indent 4 in django Rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, crud

***Django Rest Framework***

When ever I am creating a new resource, the id/pk increments by 1. Suppose I have created a resource with id no. 7 and I delete it and if again I want to create another resource, it's automatically assigning to the next id no.

Check the id no.s in my code;

"pk": 1,

"pk": 2,

"pk": 3,

"pk": **19**

```
[
{
    "model": "withoutrest.employee",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "eno": 100,
        "ename": "a",
        "esal": 20000.0,
        "eaddr": "hyd"
    }
},
{
    "model": "withoutrest.employee",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "eno": 2,
        "ename": "b",
        "esal": 30000.0,
        "eaddr": "bangalore"
    }
},
{
    "model": "withoutrest.employee",
    "pk": 3,
    "fields": {
        "eno": 3,
        "ename": "c",
        "esal": 40000.0,
        "eaddr": "delhi"
    }
},
{
    "model": "withoutrest.employee",
    "pk": 19,
    "fields": {
        "eno": 700,
        "ename": "Minnie",
        "esal": 10000.0,
        "eaddr": "Cuttack"
    }
}
]
```

Comment: It's not really django issue. Its the db thing and there is a reason behind it. pk is auto incrementing and is one-way street meaning it increments does not decrease. You can add another field where it track ordering of things.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Now i got to know each id holds unique value only.

Comment: Id field helps to know the serial values itself.